# How to make Selenium select value in <ul> drop down list?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I need to write an automated test for a web page at work, the test needs to select at least one value from a drop down list that was created with the  tag. Changing the HTML is not a good option, because I can't change the look and feel of the web page.

An example of the relevant HTML is below. This is for a drop down labeled "Self Test", and the two options are TRUE and FALSE. How can I use Selenium to automatically select the TRUE option, for instance? The Select class does not work.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-input btn-group-sm input-group input-group-sm form-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">Self Test</span>
   <button id="Self Test" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span data-bind="text: config():selfTest"></span><span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul id="selfTestDropDown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li role="presentation" data-bind="if: 0 === booleanOptions().length">
         <a role="menuitem" href="#" class="disableLink" data-bind="click: function() {}">No Data</a>
      </li>
      <!-- ko foreach: booleanOptions() -->
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: function(){config.selfTest($data);}">
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't have the `TRUE` option in html that you shared above.

Comment: when you inspect "TRUE" which element does it shows from above `html` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can click /hover on the  id="Self Test" button based on the functionality of the page and then select the option you want. because it is not part of select tag so, we cannot go with the traditional select class of selenium option.

So it would look something like :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Self Test")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("selfTestDropDown").click();
```

then find Element what you want...